# Rails console issue with attr_encrypted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, encryption, rails-console, attr-encrypted

I am using rails [attr_encrypted](https://github.com/attr-encrypted/attr_encrypted) gem for encrypting data before storing in database. It works fine on my application as it encrypts with the provided key and decrypts it using the same key via my application. But when I create a instance with my rails console, it does not encrypt with the key that is provided in the application (
uses some random key each time maybe) and hence I am not able to decrypt it when I see that instance in my application.

Below picture shows that if I create the user with the same name twice in console, each time the encrypted data is different. I am following the tutorial on this [page](http://www.kendrickcoleman.com/index.php/Tech-Blog/encrypting-data-using-attr-encrypted-with-rails.html)
 [image]

When I try to access the page  on my application, the user made by console are showing this error[image]

Here is my code for my model.rb file and am using a temporary key for demo purpose:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_encrypted_options.merge!(:encode => true)

  attr_encrypted :user, key: "aMI9uV87sL46Nwv+8qeAOUp5nsvzp5C/FkVAOFkcCtk="
  attr_encrypted :password, key: "aMI9uV87sL46Nwv+8qeAOUp5nsvzp5C/FkVAOFkcCtk="


end
```

Here is my controller code:

```
class ModelsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_model, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /models
  # GET /models.json
  def index
    @models = Model.all
  end

  # GET /models/1
  # GET /models/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /models/new
  def new
    @model = Model.new
  end

  # GET /models/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /models
  # POST /models.json
  def create
    @model = Model.new(model_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @model.save
        format.html { redirect_to @model, notice: 'Model was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @model }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @model.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /models/1
  # PATCH/PUT /models/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @model.update(model_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @model, notice: 'Model was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @model }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @model.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /models/1
  # DELETE /models/1.json
  def destroy
    @model.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to models_url, notice: 'Model was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_model
      @model = Model.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def model_params
      params.require(:model).permit(:user, :password, :host)
    end
end
```

Comment: But you are able to decrypt those back, aren't you?

Comment: No, am not ble to decrypt the ones I create via console (because I guess it uses different/random key). I am able to decrypt the ones that I create from my app when it is running (via end user view).